# Detect a click each time a a checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've figured out how to detect a click, but don't know how to detect it with the creation of each new checkbox. I think that I need to tell the machine that each checkbox has an index so that it'll iterate over each new one and show my alert message, but I can't quite figure it out. I'm just learning vanilla JS, so please, no JQuery. Thank you!

```js
var inpt = document.getElementById('inpt');

inpt.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  var list = document.getElementById('list');
  var inptVal = document.getElementById('inpt').value;
  var newItem = document.createElement('li');
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.setAttribute('id', 'check');
  
  /*when the enter button is pushed, add item.*/
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    /*append a new li to the ul with the text from the box*/
    list.appendChild(checkbox);
    list.appendChild(newItem).innerHTML = inptVal;
    inpt.value = ' ';
  }
  
  if(document.getElementById('check').onclick = function(){
    newItem.innerHTML = ' ';
    alert('You finished this task!');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type=input id='inpt'></input>
  <ul id='list'></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you bind the event to the input... `checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(){})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if(document.getElementById('check').onclick = function(){
    newItem.innerHTML = ' ';
    alert('You finished this task!');
  });
```

Weird. Remove the `if( )`.

Anyway, you're trying to select it from the DOM, but it may not be appended yet depending on the previous condition. Either way, you're apparently creating multiple elements with the same ID, so selecting by ID just won't work.

Instead, you already have the element, so just use that reference to add the handler.

```
  checkbox.onclick = function(){
    newItem.innerHTML = ' ';
    alert('You finished this task!');
  }
```

Comment: Great! Thank you; it works! Should I be creating elements using classname if I want to make multiples? Forgive my ignorance. It's been a little over 2 years since I've coded anything.

Comment: Yes, an ID should be unique on the page. To designate a common name, use a class. An element may have multiple space-separated classes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

For pure javascript check all input type checkbox dynamically

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
      x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('Click on every checkbox')
});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that I should implement a for loop, but wasn't sure how.